# xml schema - substitutiongroup with one element appear no more than once

Tags: xml, schema

I'm trying to create a list of elements of different types but I need to restrict one of types to appear no more than once. Here is example:

```
<links>
    <linktype1 id="1" />
    <linktype3 id="2" />
    <linktype2 id="3" />
    <linktypespecific id="4" />
    <linktype3 id="5" />
</links>
```

I want to allow any number of linktype1, linktype2, linktype3 in any order but linktypespecific could appear anywhere within links but no more than once.

Currently I implemented all types with the substitutiongroup, but it does not allow to restrict number of linktypespecific appearance.

Is it possible to implement that at all with XML Schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible in XSD 1.0.

You can do it in XSD 1.1 with an xs:any content model that lists the elements permitted, with maxOccurs clauses to define how often each may appear.

You can't do this with substitution groups - if an element is in a substitution group then it's fully interchangeable with the substitution group head. However (in XSD 1.1) you could use a substitution group plus an assertion to constrain the cardinality.

Comment: Finally decided that it's not so bad to have linktypespecific always on top if present so rewrote XSD using sequence with linktypespecific  and choice of linktype1, linktype2 and linktype3.